# Ext.getStore() shortcut?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2

Is there a known shortcut to reference stores in the code?

I have been using `Ext.getStore('MyStore')` all the time, but now realized that it's not the best practice as when the store's ID is changed you have to dig thru your code renaming every mention of it.

As a quick and dirty solution, I was thinking to store it in a variable at the app init:

```
App.MyStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
```

And then reference that variable as

```
App.MyStore.load();
```

I was just curious if there is a known better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my applications I usually add injection.
There is one "config class" that holds the stores (declared with Ext.getStore("...");) and it injects the stores into the components/controllers that need it.

That way, if you need to rename something or change a store, in a controller for example, you just need to alter the config class and nothing more.

**Edit**

So you would have one "config" class that *could* look like this

```
beans: [
    {
       className : "MyApp.store.myStore",
       ref: "myStore"
    },
    {
       value: "some string value",
       ref: "myValue"
    }],

mapping: [
     {
         className: "MyApp.controller.MyController",
         references:
         [
           "myStore",
           "myValue"
         ]
     },
     {
         className: "MyApp.controller.someOtherController",
         references:
         [
            "myStore"
         ]
     }
]
```

Then you would write another "injection" class that uses this config to inject the "beans" into the other classes by using the **ref** value.

The advantage here is that you could change the className of the myStore ref to something else and all of your injected classes would have an instance of the **new** class.

For example, say you are just injecting stores into controllers at this point and nothing else.

You could write another controller class with a method like this:
(imagine you have a reference to your config class -- this.config)

```
injectStores: function()
{
    //get the mapping
    var mapping = this.config.mapping;

    //go over every item in the mapping
    for(var k in mapping){ 

        //this makes the code a little easier to write
        var ref = mapping[k];

        //get the controller you will inject stores in
        var controller = this.getController(ref.className); 

        //loop over all of the references
        for(var j in ref.references){  

           //use the helper method to get the correct store name 
           var storeName = this._getBean(ref.references[j].className);
           //and then use Extjs' method to get the store instance
           var store = this.getStore(storeName); 

           //add a reference to the store in your controller
           controller[j] = store; 
        }
    }

},

_getBean: function(beanName)
{
   //reference the beans array
   var beans = this.config.beans;

   //loop over every bean
   for(var i in beans)
   {
      //if the names match return the bean
      if(beans[i].ref === beanName)
      { 
         return beans[i];
      }
   }
   //no matches, so return null;
   //this shouldn't happen when the mapping is correct
   return null;
}
```

This being an example, I did not write out all of the checks needed to make this work.
This code will fail when it encounters the "value" attribute in the second bean for example. But you could easily write some code to handle that differently.

Again, this is code is just meant as an example to inject stores into controllers.
In this example you should be able to execute:

```
this.getController("MyApp.controller.MyController").myStore.load();
```

If the injection worked properly.

I hope this can serve as a starting point to help you on your way ;-)

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I was thinking about. Please expand. Preferably with examples

Comment: (@)Mike could you please explain with a bit more detail and examples?

Comment: I've been using Deftjs for a while now, and while it might not be very well suited for smaller applications, I really suggest you try it out some time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [deftjs.org](http://deftjs.org/).

> DeftJS enhances Ext JS and Sencha Touch’s APIs with additional
>   building blocks that enable large development teams to rapidly build
>   enterprise scale applications, leveraging best practices and proven
>   patterns discovered by top RIA developers at some of the best
>   consulting firms in the industry.

Also make sure that you use MVC pattern, then you can reference your view, store or field very easily from controller:

```
var me = this,
    view = me.getView(),
    store = view.getStore(),
    record = view.getRecord(),
    data = record.getData(),
    field = me.getMyCustomField();
```